# How to run a qasm file on IBMQ device?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, qasm

I can find many qasm examples.
How can I run them on different IBMQ devices?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a example for loading QASM, executing and displaying the result.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, execute

qasm_str = """OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";
qreg q[2];
creg c[2];
h q[0];
cx q[0],q[1];
measure q -> c;
"""

# From str.
qc = QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str(qasm_str)
# If you want to read from file, use instead
# qc = QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_file("/path/to/file.qasm")

# You can choose other backend also.
backend = Aer.get_backend("qasm_simulator")

# Execute the circuit and show the result.
job = execute(qc, backend)
result = job.result()
print(result.get_counts())
```

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to use the `QuantumCircuit` methods `QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_file()` or `QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str()` depending on if your loading the QASM from a file or Python string, respectively.

Comment: Thanks. You means use QuantumCircuit methods in Jupyter notebook?

Comment: You can use them anywhere to construct a circuit from QASM code.

Answer (score -3):

```
from qiskit import *
simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation, i.e. how the code solve a problem in the question.

Comment: Shall I link GitHub repository inorder to do tat?

Comment: Reddy: It is also possible, but please add some comments, like where to put your code etc. Please take some inspiration from another answers - look for tag Qiskit.